# wrong jarjar maven plugin configuration

Tags: android, maven, pom.xml, jarjar

This is the jarjar plugin configuration.I need to add this plugin to replace **java.beans** by **harmony.beans** because in android we can't use java.Beans.

```
<build>
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>jarjar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <!-- <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version> -->
      <configuration>
        <includes>
          <include>com.myproject.adhoc:beans-harmony</include>
        </includes>
        <rules>
          <rule>
            <pattern>com.myproject.adhoc.**</pattern>
                 <result>com.myproject.util.beans.**</result> 
          </rule>
          <keep>
            <pattern>org.apache.harmony.beans.**</pattern>
          </keep>
        </rules>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

I think I have errors at result tag, please how can I fix it?